# Embedded ListView in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I want to use a listView in my program. However, I also want to use some different components(Button, TextEdit etc.) in the same window. How can i do it?

Comment: There are plently of examples available on net at this time, so its better you do Google first: http://goo.gl/yIc46

Comment: Or Check these examples: http://goo.gl/Dr9uY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use Base Adapter for that. It is simple. There are four methods Inside this 
1.getCount
2.getItem
3.getItemId
4.getView

class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {

```
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return count;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arr[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View rowView = view;

        if(rowView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(QuickSearchingWithAndroid.this);
            rowView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_view,parent,false);
        }

        WebView webView1 = (WebView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.webview1);

        webView1.loadUrl("http://www.google.co.in");


        return rowView;
    }

}
```

Then we have to create the object of the class and set That Object as:
CustomListAdapter customListAdapter = new CustomListAdapter();
listView.setAdapter(customListAdapter);

Above two lines you have to do inside the onStart or onCreate method. 
I hope this will solve your problem...just check how the layout file has to create because their is two layout file has to create.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of extending ListActivity, just use a regular activity and instantiate your list view like this:

```
listView.setAdapter( new CustomAdapter( this, R.layout.list_item, responses ) );
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled( true );
    listView.setOnItemClickListener( new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        public void onItemClick( AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id ) {
            try
            {
                Intent i = new Intent().setClass( getParent(), GuideActivity.class );
                i.putExtra( "action", "nextstep" );
                i.putExtra( "session", currentStep.getSession() );
                i.putExtra( "step", currentStep.getStep() );
                i.putExtra( "response", currentStep.getResponse( position ).getId() );
                TabGroupActivity parentActivity = ( TabGroupActivity ) getParent();
                parentActivity.startChildActivity( currentStep.getStep(), i );
            }
            catch( Exception e )
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

You will of course have to do some customization since this is taken directly from my own application.

I made my own adapter for this application. You should probably use an ArrayAdapter instead.